# I can't activate my API client

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I create a new API Client, but only approve basic permission.

And I can´t POST comment, or view users/self/follows.

Api reponse follow message

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 400,
        "error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException",
        "error_message": "This client has not been approved to access this resource."
    }
}
```

Can you helpme?
Any suggestion?

Comment: Well a 400 error means bad request. What means that there is something wrong with your credentials or your access through the API. Look at the response text - Instagram typically returns a JSON message telling you what's wrong.

`InstagramAPI.LastResponse.text`

Comment: Yes, I need **comments**, **follower_list**, **public_content** and **relationships**, permissions! How do I get them?

Comment: you need to submit app for review

Comment: Yes, I do it, But only aprove Basic permission, and get an error when I try another submition.